# Realm one to many relationship only working one sided in Swift 3 for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, realm

I have two different classes with One to Many Relationship:

```
class Car: Object {
    dynamic var Id = NSUUID().uuidString
    dynamic var Name : String = ""
    dynamic var FuelCapacity : Int = 0

    let FuelRecords = List<FuelRecord>()


    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "Id"
    }


}

class FuelRecord: Object {

    dynamic var Odometer : Float = 0.0
    dynamic var LiterPrice : Float = 0.0
    dynamic var Date = NSDate()
    dynamic var CarObject : Car?

}
```

When saving the FuelRecord object, Fuelrecord is getting linked to Car, but, CarObject is not getting linked to the FuelRecord.

As you can see, the car is linked to 0 FuelRecords

[Click here to view Cars Table in Realm Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/saaJA.png)

But the FuelRecord contains the Car reference

[Click here to view FuelRecords Table in Realm Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZyjc.png)

Due to the problem, I am unable to fetch the Fuel Records of a specific car.

This is how I am saving the FuelRecord to database.

```
fuelRecord.LiterPrice = Float(txtLiterPrice.text!)!
fuelRecord.Odometer = Float(txtOdometer.text!)!
fuelRecord.Total = Float(txtTotal.text!)!
fuelRecord.Volume = Float(txtVolume.text!)!
fuelRecord.IsPartial = switchPartial.isOn




let realm = try! Realm()

try! realm.write{
realm.add(fuelRecord)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post how you save the fuelRecord object? Inside this function YOU should also save the FuelRecord inside the CarObject list

Comment: `fuelRecord.LiterPrice = Float(txtLiterPrice.text!)!
fuelRecord.Odometer = Float(txtOdometer.text!)!
fuelRecord.Total = Float(txtTotal.text!)!
fuelRecord.Volume = Float(txtVolume.text!)!
fuelRecord.IsPartial = switchPartial.isOn




let realm = try! Realm()

try! realm.write{
realm.add(fuelRecord)`

Comment: As I thought you're not saving the FuelRecord in the Car Object, you need to create a function that add FuelRecord to the CarObject each time after have created the FuelRecord. It's not done by Realm itself. You need to implement this behavior.

Comment: Can you please guide me with the code? I mean can you please write that code for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One to many relationships are unidirectional. To find all FuelRecords associated with a car automatically and hence make the relationship bidirectional you should use Inverse relationships. This can be achieved through LinkingObjects.

Change the declaration of FuelRecords in your Car class to the following:

```
let FuelRecords = LinkingObjects(fromType: FuelRecord.self, property: "CarObject")
```

Sadly Realm Browser still won't show you the Inverse Relationship (at least this is the case for me), but you will be able to query all FuelRecords associated with a car from code.

Answer (score 0):

In your code it's missing the part where you insert the CarObject inside the FuelRecord object. By the way: I would implement a method inside the Car class:

```
class Car: Object {
   func addFuelRecordToCar(record : FuelRecord) {
      self.FuelRecords.append(record)
   }
}
```

After this, whenever you create the fuel record as you did:

```
fuelRecord.LiterPrice = Float(txtLiterPrice.text!)!
fuelRecord.Odometer = Float(txtOdometer.text!)!
fuelRecord.Total = Float(txtTotal.text!)!
fuelRecord.Volume = Float(txtVolume.text!)!
fuelRecord.IsPartial = switchPartial.isOn

// You missed how you insert the CarObject inside your FuelRecord
// I guess it's something like this
fuelRecord.CarObject = car

/* insert here */

let realm = try! Realm()

try! realm.write{
realm.add(fuelRecord)
```

Insert the following code in the right part:

```
car.addFuelRecordToCar(record: fuelRecord)
```

This should work. Let me know :)

Comment: So Everytime, I have to fetch all the fuelrecords of a particular car, update them, and then re-save the car object to the database?

Comment: By updating them you mean to change the ObjectCar they are related to? In that case, yes, you need to remove the FuelRecord manually from the Car object, and update the FuelRecord reference to the car as well. I think this is redundant, you need to decide to have the FuelRecord inside the Car object (in the list) or to have a link (the reference to the Car object) in the FuelRecord object